How to set css radial-gradient (drawing) on cairo surface in gtk4?
I am trying to draw circle on Gtk4 GtkDrawingarea using CSS. And then clicking on it, it will save as a PNG file. But unable to get the drawing (gradient) from drawing area to cairo surface (cairo_surface_t).
Can the draw done through css be saved in any way? Here is my code,
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

//draw function
static void
draw_function (GtkDrawingArea *darea,
               cairo_t        *cr,
               int             width,
               int             height,
               gpointer        user_data)
{
  GdkDisplay *display = gdk_display_get_default ();
  GtkCssProvider* provider = gtk_css_provider_new ();
  gtk_css_provider_load_from_data (provider, 
                                  "#darea { border-radius: 50%;"
                                  "  background: radial-gradient(#FFFFFF, #000000); "
                                  "}",-1);
  gtk_style_context_add_provider (gtk_widget_get_style_context (GTK_WIDGET (darea)),
                              GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER (provider),GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);

g_object_unref(provider);
}

/*save as png on click*/
void click_event (GtkEventController *gesture,
                           gdouble x,
                           gdouble y,
                           gpointer user_data)
{
 //user_data = darea (widget)
  int w1 = gtk_widget_get_allocated_width(user_data);
  int h1 = gtk_widget_get_allocated_height(user_data);

  /*paintable from the darea widget*/
  GdkPaintable* paintable = gtk_widget_paintable_new (user_data);

 /*take snapshoot*/
  GdkSnapshot* snapshot = gtk_snapshot_new();
  gdk_paintable_snapshot (paintable, snapshot, w1, h1); 

  graphene_rect_t *rec = graphene_rect_alloc ();
  GskRenderNode* ren = gsk_cairo_node_new (rec);

  cairo_t* cr = gtk_snapshot_append_cairo (snapshot, rec);
  cairo_surface_t* srf = gsk_cairo_node_get_surface ((GskRenderNode *)ren);

  cairo_surface_write_to_png (srf, "blur.png"); //use it -error Segmentation fault
}


static void
activate (GtkApplication* app,
          gpointer        user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 200, 200);
  gtk_window_present (GTK_WINDOW (window));


  GtkWidget *darea = gtk_drawing_area_new();
  gtk_widget_set_name (darea, "darea");
  gtk_drawing_area_set_content_width (GTK_DRAWING_AREA (darea), 350);
  gtk_drawing_area_set_content_height (GTK_DRAWING_AREA (darea), 350);
  gtk_drawing_area_set_draw_func (GTK_DRAWING_AREA (darea),
                                  draw_function,
                                  NULL, NULL);
  gtk_window_set_child (GTK_WINDOW (window), darea);

  //create gesture for mouse click event
    GtkGesture * = gtk_gesture_click_new();
    gtk_gesture_single_set_button(GTK_GESTURE_SINGLE(gesture), 0);
    gtk_widget_add_controller(darea,(GTK_EVENT_CONTROLLER(gesture)));
    g_signal_connect (gesture, "pressed", G_CALLBACK (click_event), darea); 

  gtk_window_present (GTK_WINDOW(window));
}

int
main (int    argc,
      char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;
  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_FLAGS);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}

But it's not working, it crashed!

It seems to me that there is a fundamental problem of understanding here.
"GtkDrawingArea is a widget that allows drawing with cairo.....It’s essentially a blank widget; you can draw on it. "  (see documentation)
In this example, however, nothing is drawn at all, but only the widget is formatted with the help of CSS.So there is no drawing in the memory that could be printed out, and so the program crashes.
Sorry.
But GTK4 doesn't seem to be a way to extract the pixel structure from a widget and then convert it to an image file.  The respective system tools are to be used here. :-(
The documentation says:
"Stop using gdk_pixbuf_get_from_window() and gdk_cairo_set_source_window()
These functions are not supported in GTK 4. Instead, either use backend-specific APIs, or render your widgets using Gtk.WidgetClass.snapshot, once you are using GTK 4."

Now tried it with GtkGLArea, but same result with GdkGLContext,
GdkSurface *gl_surf = gdk_gl_context_get_surface ((GdkGLContext * *)context); 
GdkCairoContext *cr_contxt = gdk_surface_create_cairo_context ((GdkSurface *)gl_surf);  
cairo_t *cr = gdk_cairo_context_cairo_create(cr_contxt);
